# IIViewDeckController not working, showing black screen

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, iiviewdeckcontroller

I have been trying to use the `IIViewDeckController` available [here](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck) but I am having some trouble in this.

I have created a view controller in my `storyboard` and assigned the class `IIViewDeckController` and created a segue. In my root view controller I have then set-up the controller with a centre and a left controller using the properties explained in the documentation linked above. I set-up the controller as show below

```
if([segue.identifier  isEqual: @"Deck"])
{
    // prepare view controllers
    CategoriesViewController* leftController = [[CategoriesViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController* rightController = nil;
    ListingViewController* middle = [[ListingViewController alloc] init];

    IIViewDeckController* deck = segue.destinationViewController;
    deck.centerController = middle;
    deck.leftController = leftController;
}
```

I don't get any errors when I run the code but I am presented with a black screen which does not respond to swipe events nor does it contain my Listing view.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.

In your storyboard's scene and in your target view controller, check to make sure that the views are wired up (connected) properly.

I had a tableView with a connection to the view controller's parent view as well as to the tableView itself.

Making sure that there was only one connection and that it was only to the view controller's tableView solved the issue.